# How to disable a CSS rule

Tags: html, css

I am using a Wordpress carousel plugin which sets a CSS rule

```
body * {
  line-height:1.2em;
}
```

This is causing trouble in my layout. The line height in my CSS for `body` is

```
body{ line-height: 19px;}
```

So I override `body *` as `{line-height:19px}` but it still breaks some of the layout. When I remove that rule using Firebug, everything works fine.

Now the problem here is, I dont want to edit the plugin CSS file, as every time I update it, I will have to do it.

Is there a way I can nullify the effect of `body *`?

This declaration is taking precedence over all other `line-height` properties.

Here is the [link](http://everesttravel.com.au/wp/). The CSS file loaded by a carousel plugin is breaking the navigation.

Comment: As an aside, that's bad behavior for a plugin. I'd contact the author of the plugin and suggest he not reset every element in the document with that style but rather scope the style to the contents inside the carousel.

Answer (score 3):

Reset the line-height by overriding it like this:

```
body * { line-height: inherit; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better declare an `id` for the body element, it has highest specificity and than apply the `line-height`

```
<style>
#super_container {
   line-height: 19px;
}
</style>

<body id="super_container">
    <!-- All stuff goes here -->
</body>
```

Or you can use an inline style which has the highest specificity, which will over-ride any defined style for `<body>` but that will be tedious if you want to change you need to change on each and every page...

Comment: `body *` is still taking precedence.. as down the tree, the plugin is resetting everything inside `body`. If I give `body` an ID, I will have to rewrite the css and keep all the selecter in hierarchy of that ID

Comment: @Broncha oh god are you using nested rules kinda `body ul li {}`, because this is a good way to go, using `!important` and stuff will mess up the layout and will bring you more 10 lines of over-rides, I suggest you to take some time, take a look here, apply and see

Comment: I tried using this. But didn't work. I dont have selectors nested like `body ul li` but I think the reason it didn't work is, I nned to declare other selectors as `#super_container ul li` for this t work as `body *` would have high specificity than just `ul li`

Comment: @Broncha take a look at css specificity, this is too much specific `body ul li` but ofcourse using this makes it more specific `#super_container ul li`

Comment: Yes thats the point.. Right now I have `ul li` and now I would need to add `#super_container` everywhere :)

Comment: @Broncha Better modify the plugin :p

Comment: Guess its time I find another plugin ;) but sure got to flag this one.

Comment: @Broncha haha I was going to say that but I thought you really liked the plugin and wanted to stick to

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
body * { line-height: 19px !important;}
```

this will override any other line height being set in other css file , alternativly you can put this in HTML

```
<style>
    body * { line-height: 19px}
</style>
```

style elements in HTML override all css files

or...  you can do this

```
<body style="line-height: 19px;"> ... </body>
```

inline css in elements overrides all css files , and `<style>` elements

Comment: Nope. Does not work. `body *` still taking precedence. Even when I put the inline style.

Comment: @Broncha - edited answer , try the top one , use body * and the !important

Comment: That certainly overrides the property set by the plugin, but also resets the line-height of all other elements to 19px, as `body *` has high precedence

Comment: Using `!important` is generally bad practice and should be a last resort.  In this case, I'd recommend fixing or removing the _root_ cause of the problem.